# How to find in html (from url) tag attributte

Tags: php, html, file-get-contents

```
   <?php 

    $html = file_get_contents('https://vine.co/v/h5PZJxYiHra/card');
    //$videoSrc = ?;
    ?>
```

With function `file_get_contents()`

I get HTML content of URL.

I need in this html find TAG 
`<source src="https://v.cdn.vine.co/r/videos/xxxxx.mp4
" type="video/mp4">`

How to get source attribute **src**?

Comment: Wow, thats gonna be some fancy traversing. Let me give it a shot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a few ways to do this.

**1. PHP DOM** - https://www.php.net/dom

This doo-hickey will make a XML/XHTML object given the source code you supply. It's kind of a tree like structure that you can traverse through.

**2. PHP XML** - http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php

Just like #1 but an older XML parser.

**3. String Literal Searching** - http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

This is an oldey but goody. Use `strpos()` to find the source tag start, then again to find the `src` tag and hopefully grab the string. It will require that the tags are perfect and doesn't leave a lot of flexibility.

```
$source = strpos($html, '<source ');
if($source!==FALSE) {
  $src_loc = strpos($html, 'src="', $source);
  if($src_loc!==FALSE) {
    $end_quote = strpos($html, '"', $src_loc + 5);
    if($end_quote!==FALSE) {
      $final_src = substr($html, $src_loc+5, $end_quote-($src_loc+5)); //TADA!
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool, only in **3.** in 7 line ($final_src...) missing brace ...quote-($src_loc+5) **)**;

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this one

```
include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$url = "https://vine.co/v/h5PZJxYiHra/card";
$html = file_get_html($url);
$ret =  $html->find('source.src');
```

Comment: -1. $html is a string. not a DOM object.

Comment: I have edited,Please check now

Comment: It requires a library. But yes that would work too, in a way. 
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/